# Integral of $2^{2^{2^x}}$?

Tags: integration, derivatives, indefinite-integrals

$$\int2^{2^{2^x}}~\mathrm{d}x$$

Derivative is $\ln^3(2)2^{2^x+x+2^{2^x}}$.

So no substitution technique can be used. So please guide, I am confused.

Is this elliptic?

Comment: Please rehearse the properties of logarithms: $\log 2^{2^{2^x}}=2^{2^x} \log 2$.

Comment: Oh yes! Please can you show how to find the integral then?

Comment: And is my chain rule integral right then?

Comment: Put $h(x)=2^x$ and remark that your function is $h(h(h(x)))$. Now apply formally the chain rule.

Comment: Yes, it is right, but for the integral?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says that no closed formula for the integral can be found...

Comment: I checked, but I don't think so. My professor gave me this question and said that there is an integral for this.

Comment: Well, $\int 2^{2^x}\, dx$ is already a special function. I wonder why another iteration can simplify the integral.

Comment: Special in which sense?

Comment: It is expressed in terms of the Ei function: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate[2^%282^x%29%2Cx]

Comment: So no answer???

Comment: This Cannot be expressed by standard functions. Sorry you probably want a proof.

Comment: may be the question is like that $\displaystyle \int 2^{2^{2^{x}}}\cdot 2^{2^{x}}\cdot 2^xdx $

Comment: Should I delete my question?

Answer (score 2):

$\int2^{2^{2^x}}~dx$

$=\int e^{2^{2^x}\ln2}~dx$

$=\int\left(1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{2^{2^xn}\ln^n2}{n!}\right)dx$

$=\int\left(1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{e^{2^xn\ln2}\ln^n2}{n!}\right)dx$

$=\int\left(1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{\ln^n2}{n!}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{2^{kx}n^k\ln^{n+k}2}{n!k!}\right)dx$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{x\ln^n2}{n!}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{2^{kx}n^k\ln^{n+k}2}{n!k!k\ln2}+C$

$=2x+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{2^{kx}n^k\ln^{n+k}2}{n!k!k\ln2}+C$

Comment: Completely lost you after second step.

Comment: Does these sums exists?